# SMS Communication Through The Internet

Tags: sms, communication, mobile-phones

If I am to send a message to a mobile device from a website and viceversa, how can that be done?

What I know: A couple of years ago I developed a simple enrollment system on J2ME platform(just for trying J2ME out). I had a mysql database that I setup in a pc/server, and for the communication I used the static IP of that server. I had a bridge, a mobile phone which was connected to the internet,  where clients would send a formatted message. That bridge then would send the message to the server, after verification and validation, the server would respond back to the bridge, and finally the bridge will forward that message to the client. (I know..I know..!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by using a mobile phone connected to your computer, but a more robust way would be to use an SMS aggregator - well known ones are [Mblox](http://www.mblox.com/) or [Hay](http://www.hslsms.com/), but a google search will show many more.

They will support both sending and receiving SMS messages

(Disclaimer: no connection with either, although my employer does use Hay)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you have 4 options:

- Having your own SMS server

OR

- Having to use the webportal for each provider you want to sent the message

OR

- Some provider let you send SMS with email to SMS

OR

- Use some services that let you send SMS via their webservices (this usually cost some money to subscribe).