# Recommendations for a Java library to SMS internationally

Tags: java, sms, sms-gateway, netbeans-plugins

I want to make an application that can send an SMS to person in another country.

I have heard that using an international SMS gateway is the best way to do it, and is cheap (possibly even free).

What is the best library for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1) Use a java library such as [smslib](http://smslib.org/), which allows direct communication with a mobile phone modem to send or receive messages.

2) Register with one of the SMS gateway providers such as [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/) or [csoft](http://www.csoft.co.uk/) and use their supplied apis. I would start by looking at the HTTP api [here](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/api_http.php) and [here](http://www.csoft.co.uk/sms/api/http_to_sms.htm).

A number of similar previous questions have covered this topic:

[Programmatic SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269/programmatic-sms)
[How do I implement an SMS service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414047/how-do-i-implement-an-sms-service)
[Sending SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548911/sending-sms)